# Regular Expression for Decimal or Blank

Tags: regex

Sorry for the potentially dumb question but I am trying to pull together a regular expression that will allow:

A number with 1 or 2 numbers before a decimal point, and 0-6 numbers after the decimal point.  However I also need to allow the field to be blank if so required.

Valid Examples

```
0.952321
1.20394
12.12
25
Blank
```

Invalid Examples

```
123.45678
1.1234567
```

Please can anyone help?

Answer (score 12):

```
^(?:\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{0,6})?)?$
```

Should do the trick.

```
\d     matches any digit
{n,m} specifies the number of occurrences
(?: ) creates an anonymous group
^     specifies the start of the string
$               the end of the string
?     means the group is optional
```

Comment: @Phil P: If one of the answers solved your problem, upvote and/or accept the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

`^(?:|\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{0,6})?)$`

The part before the pipe matches blank. The part after matches one or two digits optionally followed by a period and up to six digits. The `?:` are so we don't use capturing groups unless needed.

Hope this helps!

Comment: in your regex the . is mandatory: it doesn't match 25 in the example above

Comment: @PierrOz, yeah I rechecked the question and fixed it :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should provide the language you are using the regular expression in, many have features that will allow you to create more readable expressions. Here is a fail-safe [POSIX regex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions):

```
^([0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{0,6})?$
```

If the decimal part is optional, you can use

```
^([0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]{1,6})?)?$
```

Comment: +1 for not matching a number ending with a decimal (e.g. "25."). While not explicitly stated in the question, I would assume that requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,6})?)?$
```

Comment: Your regex would match an 8-digit integer.

Comment: @Miorel: ah ha you're right :)
I think we gonna have the same one at the end :)

Comment: Probably ;) I like how you handled the blank option, I should change mine to that!

Comment: for this collective work you should upvote my answer. I have upvoted yours :)

Answer (score 0):

Reading between the lines, I expanded the definition of acceptable input and not and assumed that you only wanted to capture the number in the format described.

For example, these numbers would capture as the number to the right and are all acceptable input:

```
"0.952321    "  0.952321             (trailing spaces stripped)       
"   1.20394 "   1.20394              (leading and trailing spaces stripped)
"12.12"            12.12             (no leading or trailing spaces)
"12.123   "      12.123
" .1234 "         .1234              (no leading digit -- start with decimal)
"25"                 25              (no decimal) 
" "                " " ?             (space. space captured or not)
"12."               12.              (1 or 2 digits, decimal, no numbers after decimal)
```

Not OK input:

```
"."                                   just a decimal
"123456789"                           more than 2 digits lefthand
123                                       ""      "" 
123.45678 
1.1234567                             more than 6 digits right hand
[a-zA_Z]                              not a digit...
```

So, given that, this regex will do it:

```
/^\s*(                  # beginning of string and strip leading space                                
 | \d{1,2}\.?           # 1 or 2 digits with optional decimal
 | \d{0,2}\.\d{1,6}     # 0,1, 2 digits with a decimal with digits 
 | \s+                  # remove if you do not want to capture space
  )\s*$                 # trailing blanks to the end
/x
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, i.e. unlimited decimal places:

`^-?(([1-9]\d*)|0)(.0*[1-9](0*[1-9])*)?$`

Answer (score 0):

I would use one of these:

To match all of your decimals:

```
(\d+\.\d+){0,1}
```

To be more specific in number before/after the point, try/variate with any of these:

```
(\d+\.\d{2}){0,1}
(\d{4}\.\d{2}){0,1}
```