# Regex to validate whole and decimal numbers in a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a textarea that can accept only whole and decimal numbers on each new line.
I need a JQuery regex that will validate the input on Focus Out. So basically the value on each line should be either an integer or a decimal.

Ex:

**Valid Scenarios:**

```
1
51425.125
2552
600000
1.51425
3.65
```

**Invalid Scenarios:**

```
.123
123.
123.  56
1213.56.25
234.   (spaces after the decimal point)
```

I have tried various regex combinations but none seemed to work perfectly:

```
\b\s([-+]?(\d+|\.\d+|\d+\.\d*))($|[^+-.])
```

This regex fails when there are 2 decimal values.

```
\b[0-9\s]*(\.*[0-9\s]*)*
```

This regex allows space in between and after values.

```
\b(?:^|\s)(?=.)((?:0|(?:[1-9](?:\d*|\d{0,2}(?:,\d{3})*)))?(?:\.\d*[1-9])?)(?!\S)
```

This regex doesn't allow the user to enter multi-line values.

Went through several links but none seems to work for me:
[Regular Expression for Decimal or Blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508673/regular-expression-for-decimal-or-blank)
[Regular expression - number with spaces and decimal comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26538636/regular-expression-number-with-spaces-and-decimal-comma)
[Decimal number regular expression, where digit after decimal is optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12117024/decimal-number-regular-expression-where-digit-after-decimal-is-optional)
http://regexone.com/problem/matching_decimal_numbers

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/a9ujzqgr/) JSFiddle:

```
/^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/gm
```

JavaScript

```
$("#input").on("input", function(){
    var validateThis = $(this).val();
    var validateCount = validateThis.split("\n").length;
    var result = validateThis.match(/^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/gm);
    if(result && result.length == validateCount){
        $("#result").text("Valid input! :)");
    } else{
        $("#result").text("Invalid input! :(");
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<textarea id="input" rows="4"></textarea>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Seem to work for given scenarios. [`/^\d+(\.\d+)?$/gm`](https://regex101.com/r/zJ7jR2/1)

Comment: This doesn't accept the new line character, and hence throws error.

Comment: @Batman Ah, missed that part of the question. Lemme see if i can tweak it.

Comment: @Batman Did you check the above link, Arg0n, use `^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$` to non-capturing groups

Comment: @Tushar Any flag to force it to check all to be valid?

Comment: @Arg0n One way could be to count number of lines, `split` by newline and get length of array. Compare with the number of matches, with `gm` flags. If both are equal, all the lines passes the regex.

Comment: @Tushar Yeah i thought of that, but was wondering if somehow it could be done in the regex. Anyway, will add to answer. Thanks!

Comment: The RegExs above doesn't seem to work when tried on this site: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/dotnet/index.html

Comment: When inspected the regex assigned to the textarea, it looks something like this: (?:^\d+(?:.\d+)?(?:\r\n)?$)+ Is this correct?

Comment: @Batman Look at the updated answer, i've added a JSFiddle for you to play with.

Comment: You'r basically splitting by \n and then applying the RegEx. But in my case, I cannot use any logics. Just assign the RegEx to the control. So can we include the \n or \r\n in our RegeEx?

Comment: You may want to tag the question with e.g. `.NET`, `RegularExpressionValidator` or something then, so we know what the final usage will be. Will remove this answer in 20 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

> So can we include the \n or \r\n in our RegeEx?

Yes, we can. Here's an expression that tests whether the whole text consists of lines with numbers:

```
^\d+(\.\d+)?(\n\d+(\.\d+)?)*\n?$
```

- `^`…`$` - The whole text must match.
- `\d+(\.\d+)?` - at least one digit, optionally followed by a period and at least one digit
- `(\n…)*` - followed by any number (including zero) of: newline with …
- `\n?` - Allow a newline at the end (if you want to).